# How to change the vesion of 'compileKotlin'

Tags: gradle, build

'compileJava' task (current target is 17) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 1.8) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

The latest version of my IDEA is 1.8, has anyone encountered this problem?
Hope your answer!